# How to fix wrongly converted text (cases: á é í ó ú ñ)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm from Venezuela and I'm working in a web app that uses an old database, the guys who made it, didn't care about the proper render of spanish caracters (á é í ó ú ñ), so there are names saved as ESPAÃ‘A O (ESPAÑA), MARTIÂN (MARTÍN).

So, I can replace the string in `SQL` like `REPLACE( name, 'Ã‘', 'Ñ' )` but, ¿there are an easy way to make this replace in all the cases?

There is just one table in MySQL (historias) with two fields (nombre, apellido) with the same problem.

I'm also using php.

Comment: Post what you've already got so that we can help you.

Comment: I was thinking in make a loop in php to update this fields, but, that's really the correct aproach?

Comment: I have a similar problem. the database tables have latin1 encoding, but lots of data are incorrect. My idea is precisely as you suggest, to manually fix every field replacing the incorrect values for the correct ones. In your case, it is pretty straightforward because you can directly substitute Â for Í, 'Ã‘' for 'Ñ', etc. My problem is worse because EVERY ñ and áéíóú are stored as '?', so I cannot directly replace them (there is no way to know the correct value for each (i.e. i have to guess that ?lvaro Obreg?n is Álvaro Obregón and Las Pe?as is Las Peñas.) I may need to build a new table.

Comment: Yep @DiegoDD I was able to fix it directly with `replace`, but in your case I would firstly search all `?` (SELECT ... LIKE '%\?%') and manually fix every one... Then try to avoid the wrong encoding in the INSERT/UPDATE action...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to retrieve the data from mysql using console, just to see how the data will appear.
If data appears properly and not broken, this may tell you that mysql is working just fine, but problem still in PHP, as PHP yet working bad with bigger part of utf-8 characters.

In case you receive broken characters from mysql in console, make a backup of your db and try to convert you database AND fields(!) to UTF8. This will consume more disk space, but, assure the safe characters.

In case the problem is in PHP, you may try a few solutions:
the one is converting string into utf8

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string_to_convert);
```

Another way, you could try just using a functions on string that are understanding utf-8(multibyte).
For more information, see: [PHP: Multibyte String - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)

HTH

Sincerely,

VR

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is in the DB, for about two years the original developers save those caracters as Ã‘ or Â. I was thinking in `UPDATE` all the records and replace those values, but maybe changing the charset to UTF8 is the anwser

Comment: Make sure you are changing the table's charset, also the field's charset to make sure, it is properly changed. maybe the database handles these characters,but the problem occurs on the inserting script that not handles the chars properly. ;-) check it and report